# .htaccess RewriteRule remove some url parts

Tags: .htaccess

I'm still new in htaccess and I want to learn it if possible but I need to finish my project first in school.

My original url is:

```
http://localhost/example/php/admin/
```

I want to rewrite it so it will only shows and also that's what will be need to write in url to access the url above:

```
http://localhost/example/admin/
```

is it possible with htaccess?
also if you have a good advice where to learn htaccess, I want to learn if possible. thanks :)

Comment: So what do you want to remove? 
Every second path parameter? Every occurrence of "php" or every path with the value of "php"?

EDIT: BTW, yes, It is possible!

Comment: only the 'php'. if I want to access `http://localhost/example/php/admin/php2/` I will have to write this in url `http://localhost/example/admin/php2/` . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^php/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: it rewrites but also redirecting you to that new url. I want to change the url but it doesn't effect where it's accessing the file.

Comment: the code i posted is just remove the php in the url .